# Eliminate word from $term->name

Tags: categories, taxonomy

Is it possible to eliminate a word from `<?php echo $term->name; ?>`

For example:

Term is "Amazing Big Screen TV'S"

But I want to put `<?php echo $term->name; ?>` in a  Tag and auto drop/edit out the word "Amazing" from the $term->name;

So out put would be:

**Big Screen TV'S**

Amazing Big Screen TV'S

Description

Answer (score 1):

You can use PHP's native function [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

Comment: Hello Jory. Thank you for the lead. I tried;

'code'
function wordFilter($term)
{
    $filtered_text = $term;
    $filtered_text = str_replace('amazing', ' ', $filtered_text);
    return $filtered_text;
}
'code'

But no luck.

Here is where I'm trying to apply
'code'
<h1 class="single dotted"><?php echo $term->name; ?></h1> 'code'

Comment: The code is incorrect, it should work if you change it to: `<h1 class="single dotted"><?php echo wordFilter( $term->name ); ?></h1>`

Comment: Also, your function can be simplified: `function wordFilter($text) {
 return = str_replace('amazing', ' ', $text);
}`